# What sort of program has its PE executable header set to ROM image?

Tags: windows, file-format

The specification for Windows PE executables (available over [here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx) or in winnt.h) says that if the Magic field in the Optional Header is set to 0x107 then the program is a ROM image.

But an image of what ROM?

What kinds of programs would they be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the "kinds of programs" are used by EFI. See [IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_EFI_ROM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680339(VS.85).aspx).